# Airflow grouping DAGs by common id or params

Tags: architecture, airflow, pipeline

In Airflow most pipeline consists of a group of DAGs each DAG contains tightly related tasks.
Does Airflow have some construct/object which can group DAGs together? So that one can track the success or failure of the whole pipeline?

Something like in the picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To create a relationship between two separate dags, airflow provides [ExternalTaskSensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.3/_api/airflow/sensors/external_task_sensor/index.html) to add a dependency to a task in another dag. When you use this sensor, you can access the graph of DAG dependencies available on `<AIRFLOW_SERVER_URI>/dag-dependencies`.

Also, Airflow provide an experimental lineage support based on OpenLineage, which allows you to use an external lineage platforms (ex: Marquez). By using a lineage tool, you can define the dependencies between the different airfow dags to create bigger business/functional dags, and track the success or failure of the whole pipeline.